# How do I find all the distinct keys of json records in c#?

Tags: c#, json

Why this question is **not duplicate**? (Added after seeing comments)

- It is not related to Entity framework.
- It has to deal with parsing huge json files and find distinct keys, but not records!

I've 200+ files and each of them is 2+ GB, implies total size is 400+ GB. Each line in those files is a json string. I don't have `json schema` for the records beforehand. My job is to find all the keys in those files.

I wrote following code to get all the distinct keys from all those json records. I call following method using multi-threaded `for-loop` from `main`.

```
private void GetTokensFromJson(string filePath)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> txts = File.ReadLines(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);

            Console.WriteLine(txts.Count());

            List<string> distinctKeys = new List<string>();

            foreach (var text in txts)
            {

                    string pattern = "{\"";

                    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(text, pattern))
                    {
                        //string matchValue = m.Value;
                        int matchIndex = m.Index;
                        string subStr=text.Substring(matchIndex+2, text.Length - matchIndex - 3);
                        int quoteIndex=subStr.IndexOf('\"');
                        string jsonKey = subStr.Substring(0, quoteIndex);
                        if (!distinctKeys.Contains(jsonKey) && !jsonKey.Contains("\\"))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(jsonKey);
                            distinctKeys.Add(jsonKey);
                        }
                    }

                string secondPattern="\":";
                foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(text, secondPattern))
                {
                    int matchIndex = m.Index;
                    string revJsonKKey = "";
                    while(matchIndex>0)
                    {
                        matchIndex--;
                        if (text[matchIndex] != '\"')
                            revJsonKKey += text[matchIndex];
                        else
                            break;
                    }

                    IEnumerable<char> jsonKeyCharArray = revJsonKKey.Reverse();
                    string jsonKey="";
                    foreach(char c in jsonKeyCharArray)
                    {
                        jsonKey += c;
                    }

                    if (!distinctKeys.Contains(jsonKey) && !jsonKey.Contains("\\"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(jsonKey);
                        distinctKeys.Add(jsonKey);
                    }

                }

            }
```

`distinctKeys` has all the distinct json keys. But I'm missing few keys and adding unwanted keys, not sure why :|. I can't debug for the given input, as it is too huge! Also, this method is too slow.

To make things clearer, let's take an example, if files have following json,

```
{"id":"123", "name":"hello, world", "department":[{"name":"dept1", "deptID":"123"}]}
{"id":"456324", "department":[{"name":"dept2", "deptID":"456"}]}
```

Expected **output** is `id,name,department, department->name, department->deptID`. Formatting of output doesn't matter. Note that not all the json records will not have all the keys and json record can contain nested json records.

I've **two** questions,

1. What am I doing wrong in the code?
2. Is there a inbuilt or 3rd-party dll which will give me output as keys of json, when I give input as complex json record?

Comment: You have two questions in one, and I'm afraid both of them can flag the whole thing as an off-topic question. _why isn't this code working?_ and _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_

Comment: I guess, you understand my intentions :) Can you help me in fixing the question? Anyways, code is working, but has a bug :|

Comment: It isn't helping my cause, as I need to parse json here and in entity framework you know the keys! You have to just do distinct. I don't want to find distinct records.

Comment: @dbc, OP mentions that each line of that file contains an individual JSON object, not that the entire file represents an object.

Comment: @dbc Whole file itself isn't json. Every line is a json. So, `{"id":"456324", "department":[{"name":"dept2", "deptID":"456"}]}` is a json and line above it as well, but not together. I have to parse lines one-by-one.

Comment: @easuter thanks for helping me out in explaining the question :)

Comment: What are your "keys". Is it the "id" field? What should become distinct, what should be done when you find lines with the same "id" (or key)? Please add to your question: the implicit schema of (1) an input line (2) an output "record" (including their data types), as well as what the key is, and what to do with duplicate keys

Comment: @Alex my keys are the "id" and other string which come to the left of key-value pair in json. If you see in first json, name is present twice. First is as-it-is and second is in nested json. So, I would need them to be nested, as shared in expected output.

Comment: By "distinct keys", do you mean all *unique* encountered combinations of `id,name,department, department->name, department->deptID`?

Comment: @dbc Yes, that is what I meant distinct keys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with Json.net, That Path property contains the full path of that object

```
 private static void GetKeys(JObject obj, List<string> keys)
    {
        var result = obj.Descendants()
            .Where(f => f is JProperty) //.Where(f => f is JProperty) 
            .Select(f => f as JProperty)// and .Select(f => f as JProperty) can be replaced with .OfType<JProperty>()
            .Select(f=>f.Path)
            .Where(f=> !keys.Contains(f));
        keys.AddRange(result);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {         
        IEnumerable<string> txts = @"{'id':'123', 'name':'hello, world',     'department':[{'name':'dept1', 'deptID':'123'}]}
{'id':'456324', 'department':[{'name':'dept2', 'deptID':'456'}]}".Split("\r\n".ToArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        List<string> keys = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in txts)
        {
            var obj = JObject.Parse(item);
            GetKeys(obj, keys);
        }
```

}

Comment: trying it. Give me some time :)

Comment: Awesome!! Upvoted. Thanks, it is working as expected!! Do you mind explaining the LINQ query? It is not clear to me, how is it going to all the descendants.

Comment: `Where(f => f is JProperty)` will eliminate all objects that aren't a property; `Select(f => f as JProperty)` will cast each anonymous descendent object `f` into a `JProperty` class instance; `Select(f=>f.Path)` will "transform" each of these instances into a string (`Path`); the last `Where` will prevent duplicates from being added to the `keys` list.

You could also avoid that last `Where` by using a `HashSet<string>` instead of a `List`, since it won't allow duplicates in the first place.

Comment: @Abhishek, no problem! I highly recommend becoming familiar with Linq sooner rather than later; it will generally make you more productive and make your code clearer. If you want a book recommendation it, I'll point you to the "Thinking in Linq" book. :)

Comment: @easuter Thanks for the advice, will look into it ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Read the strings into JSON.NET and convert them to Jobjects

Then loop through Jobjects

```
 foreach ( jobject in jobjects )   
{
 IList<string> keys = jobject .Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
}
```

then do

```
keys.distinct();
```

It will be like

```
 private void GetTokensFromJson(string filePath)
            {
                IEnumerable<string> txts = File.ReadLines(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);
    List<JObject> jObjects = new List<JObject>() {};
    IList<string> keyslist;

                Console.WriteLine(txts.Count());

                List<string> distinctKeys = new List<string>();

                foreach (var text in txts)
                {

                      var obj = JObject.Parse(text); 
                      jObjects.add(obj);  


                }
    for each ( jobject in jobjects )   
    {
     IList<string> keys = jobject .Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
    keyslist.add(keys);
    }
    keyslist.distinct();

         }
```

Comment: What is `json.net`? Any sample which takes json string and return JObject without me giving schema of json?

Comment: [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is a very popular library to work with `JSON` on `C#`. You can serialize/deserialize data without knowing the schema beforehand.

Comment: You can install the nuget through visual studio

Comment: @KennerDev Got it! But when I read the documentation, it expects me to give schema/class. I don't have schema for the json records. I couldn't find function which takes string and give me object/keys without me specifying class/schema

Comment: It is not a requirement. you can use dynamic type as well

Comment: JObject json = JObject.Parse("json str you read from your file" );

Comment: @Abhishek, you can use the `DeserializeObject` method to obtain a `dynamic` object. Just keep in mind that using `dynamic` will be slower than deserializing objects against a schema.

Comment: See the above answer from @nhabuiduc. it is very clear how to do it

Comment: @KennerDev Let me give it a try, and get back.

Comment: `JObject.Parse("json str you read from your file" );` is not working for nested json/arrays. :|

Comment: See my updated answer and also do some validation on strings you read from file.

Comment: @KennerDev, just a detail in your answer: `for each` isn't valid C#.

Comment: @KennerDev easuter is right. Anyways, you showed me new library json.net. Upvoted for pointing me to it

Comment: @easuter  updated it . Thanks.I was going for simple english explanation and changed my mind to write some code

Answer (score 1):

Let's do the math shall we. You have:

- 200 files
- of at least 2 GB
- where a line is, lets say 120 characters (240 bytes) on average

That makes for 400 GB Internal memory just for holding all content and for
1,789,569,707, i.e. nearly 2 **billion** lines.

Clearly your problem here is **not** one that is related to parsing, but to managing your memory and indexing on keys in an incremental manner, using intermediate results that do not all reside in memory.

Using the simple list that you have now to track your keys, and assuming that **1 in 20** of your keys is unique:

- You now have to maintain 125 million key entries in your index list
- If storage required for a single key index entry is 80 bytes, this will add up to the list taking 9 GB of memory.

Searching the list (125 million items) for duplicates for a new line is going to be **very** slow.

You may want to look into map/reduce style algorithms to figure out how something like this may be achieved.

Comment: I'm not storing all the files at once in memory. I'll take one line/file at a time :). Distinct keys wouldn't take so much memory.

Comment: ok, lets assume one fifth of your keys is unique, and to keep the index in memory you need 80 bytes per key in the index, then your index will be 27 GB large. You can't hold that in a simple list in memory. How much time do you think it will take to search through 500 million index items to check if a key for a new line already exists?

Comment: I also suggest you to look into object databases like mongodb or something like that instead of using text files to save your json data

Comment: @Alex 1/5th of the keys isn't be unique upto my knowledge. Unique keys wouldn't take more than 500 MB of memory. I get it, what you are trying to suggest (pig script or hadoop environment like thing). But  the answer given by **nhabuiduc** serves my purpose. :)

Answer (score 1):

A few issues:

1. Don't do `Console.WriteLine(txts.Count());`.  I believe this actually causes you to read the entire file twice -- once to count, and once to read keys.
2. Use a [`HashSet<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to collect distinct keys, it's much faster than using a list.
3. As Kenner Dev suggests, install [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and use [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to parse each line of the file without needing to know a schema.
4. Continue to read the files line-by-line as you are currently doing, don't try to load the entire thing in memory at once in any representation.

Then, `GetTokensFromJson` becomes:

```
    public static HashSet<string> GetTokensFromJson(IEnumerable<string> txts)
    {
        return new HashSet<string>(txts.Select(t => JObject.Parse(t)).Where(o => o != null).SelectMany(o => o.Descendants().OfType<JProperty>()).Select(p => p.Name));
    }
```